# how to add simple option to chartjs correctly

Tags: chart.js

Im using the following code for showing my graph of chart.js library:

HTML Part:

```
<div style="width:60%">
<div>
    <canvas id="canvas_all" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

and the Script:

```
    var lineChartDataAll = {
        labels : <?php echo json_encode($all_date_label) ?>,
        datasets : [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : <?php echo json_encode($all_hum_data) ?>
            },
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data : <?php echo json_encode($all_temp_data) ?>
            }
        ]

    }


window.onload = function(){

    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: true
    });

    var ctx_all = document.getElementById("canvas_all").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx_all).Line(lineChartDataAll, {
        responsive: true,
        showXLabels: 10
    });
}
```

Now, i have problems with this option: showXLabels: 10

Do i use this option in a correct way?

I want that there are only a view x (10) label on the x-axis ...thats the goal.

By now the graph is showing all x labels...

Comment: Chart.js does not have an option called showXLabels. However you can add one yourself. Do you just want to clip the data off above x, i.e. if you have 11 data points and x = 10, you want to show labels 1 to 10?

Comment: lets say i have 100 labels on the x axes. This would not look very nice. Therefore i thought there is an option only to show an amount of x values. Lets say 10. Then only 10 x labels are shown under the diagram. I thought there is an option look at this: https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/pull/521

Answer (score 0):

The option referenced in the (question) comments is from [PR 521](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/pull/521) that has not been merged into the main branch yet. This was later made into a [PR 897](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/pull/897), which too is yet to be merged.

So, if you want this feature, you should be using code from either of the above.

Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/trhcafut/ that does just that. I just added the following block of code to the end (just scroll to the very end of the JS block), after Chart.Core and Chart.Line from the PR.

```
var lineChartData = {
    labels : ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]
}

var ctx_all = $("#canvas_all").get(0).getContext("2d");
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx_all).Line(lineChartData, {
    showXLabels: 3
});
```

Note that you won't be getting any changes made to Chart.js after the branch if you do this.